# Bad question locked rather than deleted when it was marked as favorite by some users

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, locked-posts, bad-questions

I just marked as favorite - really fun time - a very bad question as well as other guys, and this question was deleted soon after.

Why this kind of question (-25 rep in very short time) with great SO community comments, are not *locked* instead of being deleted ?

I even hoped for a moment receive a winter hat (winter bash time) for having marked it as favorite...

Dispite of the poor quality of the question, the comments remain rather funny and instructive and are part of the spirit of the community.

Comment: the spirit of the community is "no fluff, straight to technical". How can funny mean that?  Anyway, a bad question that deserves deletion deserves deletion, full stop. Whether it's favorited by 1, 1000000, 1000000000000, or 0 users.... Why do you want it locked anyway? If it is "very bad" it has no place on our site.

Comment: This is why I err on the side of deletion whenever a case of popular/fun question comes across... the precedent is scary!

Comment: Totaly agree with that but comments are deleted too... and they not deserves being deletes

Comment: We off-load funny things to other sites. If reddit doesn't want it you can try [this](http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/)

Comment: @TGrif on Stack, comments are ephemeral and you should EXPECT them to disappear at any point. We will not keep a terrible question around because of good COMMENTS. Maybe we will keep one around for good ANSWERS, but even then the guidance would be to edit the question into shape.

Comment: Sorry the comment was for @rene... This is not very encouraging to make suggestions anyway

Comment: Voting is different on meta, @Tgrif. Here downvotes do NOT cost rep, as they are used to indicate disagreement. The -5 here isn't "your question is terrible", it's "nope, we don't agree with your suggestion".

Comment: Thank for that @Patrice, I feel better now

Comment: Oh come on... There are *much* better troll questions to laugh at than the [one you found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291457/javascript-whaaaat-constructor-is-not-a-function-how).

Comment: @Mystical, well seen! But This is not the only question I have in mind. Some locked questions realy saved my life. But who care, I will soon reach -25 by myself too...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question indicates a belief that fun in questions and answers is harmless:

> <sup>Despite of the poor quality of the question, the comments remain rather funny and instructive and are part of the spirit of the community.</sup>

If you take a closer look at [the site history described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/102937) you may find out that it is most likely not so.

Thing is, first few years fun questions were allowed at Stack Overflow where they coexisted with "boring" programming questions. Fun questions were popular, entertaining, brought a lot of views and site visits.

Now ask yourself a question, **if these were indeed harmless, why would they want to "outsource" them to a separate site (NPR)?**

Nobody in their sane mind would get rid of content that brings views and visits if it is harmless.

I bet Stack Overflow creators would be happy to keep these questions on-site if (**if**) these weren't causing harm. The very fact that they moved it to a separate site (NPR) makes a very strong indication that these were indeed considered harmful.

---

In case if you wonder about what specifically could make SO creators believe that there is harm consider taking a look at the canonical article explaining these matters - [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/):

> we discovered that these posts become so popular over time that they truly start to drown out everything else on the site...

1. **Broken windows.** Every 'fun' post users see is an open invitation for them to participate in the fun by adding *their own* fun question or answer. The stuff spreads like [kudzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudzu)! Pretty soon the entire site is overrun with nothing but that kind of fun. And even if you grandfather a few in, you'll enjoy neverending requests asking why *their* fun question or answer has to be removed, while *this one over here* is allowed to remain.

> 

2. **Opportunity cost.** Every minute spent participating in an entertaining 'fun' post is time that someone could have spent asking or answering a substantive question, something practical that solves an *actual problem* for hundreds or thousands of people. Entertainment, within reason, is by no means a bad thing -- but I experience almost physical pain when I think about a brilliant topic expert spending 10 minutes on one of our sites deciding which hilarious cartoon is their favorite.

There is quite a solid evidence that Stack Exchange Q&A model turned out poor in supporting "pure fun" kind of questions. They tried to keep these along with serious questions, they also tried to keep them at separate site... "Sadly, it didn't work out."